# Deserialize JSON with complex array members that have no labels

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm getting the following JSON:

```
{
    "NumberResults": 3,
    "Results": [
        ["1", "Name1", ""],
        ["2", "Name2", ""],
        ["17", "Name3", ""]
    ]
}
```

Which should be deserialized to the following object `Response`:

```
    public class Response
    {
        public int NumberResults { get; set; }
        public List<Result> Results { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Which API can I use to do that? I guess I must rely on the order of properties in the `Result` class, since I have no labels for the results.

Comment: Have you ever used `JSON.NET`? Check it here. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. You probably get the JSON as string in your backend, use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> Method (String)` method for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to convert json in to a c# class..

You can rename the RootObject to what you like.

http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int NumberResults { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Results { get; set; }
}
```

If you want it in the format you have then I suggest, you create the object(Response) and then convert it to json to see what the json would look like.

**Update**

to get what you want your json would have to look like

```
{
    "NumberResults": 3,
    "Results": [ 
           {"id":"1", "Name": "Name1", "Description ":  ""},
           {"id":"2", "Name": "Name2", "Description ":  ""},
           {"id":"17", "Name": "Name3", "Description ":  ""}
      ]
}
```

if you can not modify the json, then you will not be able cast it to the types you have...

You could cast it to what I gave first(RootOject). and then in code, write some functions to convert it how you want.

Comment: ok and what about public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } ?

Comment: hahahaah.... that is question @Seabizkit, how can he add `"id"` in json as you do it manually

Comment: either need to add label in json or deserialize and get data without label

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the JSON, you can handle this situation with a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) class.  The converter will translate the inner arrays into objects for you.

```
class ResultConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Result));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
        return new Result
        {
            Id = (int)array[0],
            Name = (string)array[1],
            Description = (string)array[2]
        };
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

With this converter you can deserialize the JSON into your classes like this:

```
Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json, new ResultConverter());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/csyVC4

Answer (score 1):

Based on Brian's answer, I constructed the following more generic one, which will work for other classes, which should be deserialized from similar JSONs.

```
public class GenericSearchResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
            {
                var property = objectType.GetProperty(reader.Value.ToString());
                if (property == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                reader.Read();

                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                        case JsonToken.StartArray:
                        var array = JArray.Load(reader);
                        var listInstance = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
                        var listObjectType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                        foreach (var child in array)
                        {
                            var listObjectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(listObjectType);
                            var propertyIndex = 0;
                            foreach (var subProperty in listObjectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
                            {
                                var childValue = child[propertyIndex].ToObject(subProperty.PropertyType);
                                subProperty.SetValue(listObjectInstance, childValue, null);
                                propertyIndex++;
                            }
                            listInstance.Add(listObjectInstance);
                        }

                        property.SetValue(instance, listInstance);
                        break;

                    default:
                        var value = reader.Value;
                        var typedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);
                        property.SetValue(instance, typedValue, null);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```